# How to show that the inverse under multiplication of a positive real number is positive?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

Let $a\,{\in}\,\mathbb{R}:a>0$. How do we know that $a^{-1}>0$ too?

Comment: Question of this form suggests you are asked to prove this from the axioms. What axioms are you assuming?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint.**

$a \cdot a^{-1} = 1 > 0$

Comment: I suppose you mean that ${\forall}x,y\,{\in}\,\mathbb{R}:x<0∧y>0:x⋅y<0$. How to prove this? Whenever I enter 'negative times positive' into the search bar I get only questions about how negative times negative equals positive.

Comment: This depends on the axioms in use.

Comment: Axioms of what? $\mathbb{R}$ is the totally ordered Dedekind complete field, if you mean this.

Comment: Take $x < 0$ and $y >0$. Then $-x>0$ and $-x \cdot y >0$. Hence $x \cdot y < 0$

Comment: How did you get $-x⋅y=-(x⋅y)$?

Comment: $0=0 \cdot y =(x-x) \cdot y =x \cdot y- x \cdot y$